# problems with react and "this" even after binding

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**[UPDATE]** If I go to ListItem.js and console log this.props (with or without passing props to the constructor) I can see all of the props except the method. I have also just ran the code with the entire onchange event on ListItem.js removed, and I still get the undefined error. So I'm thinking the error is coming from the HomeDepo.js page rather than the ListItem.js. Thanks everyone for your suggestions so far!

I’m new to React and I have what I’m sure will turn out to be a pretty basic error that I just cant get past.

I have a parent component that calls instances of a child component, passing (among other things) a method from the parent via a prop.

To make things slightly more complicated, the parent component is getting its state data from a separate data file, and I only want to call the child component on a subset of the objects inside the state array.

Here's what I've got:

listData.js:

```
    const listData = [
    {
        id: 1,
        store: "SaveOnFoods",
        itemText: "bread",
        purchased: false
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        store: "SaveOnFoods",
        itemText: "milk",
        purchased: false
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        store: "HomeDepo",
        itemText: "nails",
        purchased: true
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        store: "HomeDepo",
        itemText: "wood",
        purchased: false
    }
    ]

export default listData;
```

HomeDepo.js:

```
    import React from "react";

import listData from "../../../listData";
import ListItem from "../../ListItem";

import AddListItem from "../../AddListItem";

const storeStyles = {
    width: "90%",
    border: "1px solid black",
    boxShadow: "5px 10px 8px #888888",
    padding: "10px",
    margin: "20px"
}

const listStyles = {
    listStyle: "none",
}

class HomeDepo extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            listData : listData
        }
        this.updateCheckbox = this.updateCheckbox.bind(this)
    }

    updateCheckbox(id){
        console.log("changed", id)
    }

    render() {
            /* make an array of components with associated props, where the item's store is HomeDepo */

            const listComponents = this.state.listData.map(function(item) {
                if (item.store == "HomeDepo") {
                   console.log(item);
                   return (
                        <ListItem id={item.id} key={item.id} itemText={item.itemText} purchased={item.purchased} updateCheckbox={this.updateCheckbox}/>
                    )
                }
                })

        return (
            <section style={storeStyles}>
                <h3>Home Depo:</h3>
                <ul style={listStyles}>
                    {listComponents}  {/* return the array */}
                </ul>
                <AddListItem />
            </section>
        )
    }

}

export default HomeDepo;
```

ListItem.js:

```
import React from "react";

class ListItem extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input
                    type="checkbox" 
                    checked = {this.props.purchased}
                    onChange = {(event) => this.props.updateCheckbox(this.props.id)}
                    />
                <li>{this.props.itemText}</li>
            </div>
        )
        }
    }

export default ListItem;
```

The updateCheckbox method being passed through the prop is supposed to run when the checkbox is clicked.

For some reason though, I'm getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateCheckbox' of undefined

What am I missing here?

Comment: This isn't the solution, but just to let you know that if you use ES6 syntax when defining your class methods, you don't have to have bind to `this`. So the code would look like this instead: `updateCheckbox = (id) => { }`

Comment: you could try hooks, so you do not have to deal with context issues

Comment: @JossClassey thanks for the tip, that's great to know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You are getting this error because `this` does not refer to what you think it does!**

Here, `this` refers to the enclosing anonymous function, **not** to `HomeDepo`:

```
const listComponents = this.state.listData.map(function(item) {
  if (item.store == "HomeDepo") {
    console.log(item);
    return (
      <ListItem id={item.id} key={item.id} itemText={item.itemText} purchased={item.purchased} updateCheckbox={this.updateCheckbox}/>
    )
  }
})
```

And of course, this function itself doesn't have an attribute `updateCheckbox`, hence the error. You need to **bind** the *outer this* (referring to HomeDepo) to the function's *inner this*.

Two alternate solutions:

1. You can either do it « manually »:

   ```
   const listComponents = this.state.listData.map(function(item) {
     /* ... */
   }.bind(this))
   ```
2. Or, better, **simply use a fat-arrow-function** *(those are automatically this-bound):*

   ```
   const listComponents = this.state.listData.map(item => {
     /* ... */
   })
   ```

Further reading: [Understanding the "this" keyword in JS](https://medium.com/quick-code/understanding-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-cb76d4c7c5e8)

Answer (score 2):

In your **ListItem** you do not pass the props to the super.

Like so:

```
constructor(props){
   super(props)
}
```

And you are calling `this.props.updateCheckbox` on the onChange of the input.

props is undefined.

Comment: Hi C1rdec, thanks for your suggestion. After trying the above, I'm still getting the same error. Also, if I go to ListItem.js and console log this.props (with or without passing props to the constructor) I can see all of the props except the method. I have also just ran the code with the entire onchange event on ListItem.js removed, and I still get the undefined error. So I'm thinking the error is coming from the HomeDepo.js page rather than the ListItem.js

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to pass `this` into your map otherwise it's out of scope. Look at the last line of the map where it closes to see where I added it. Map takes a second argument after the function where you can pass the `this` keyword in.

```
  const listComponents = this.state.listData.map(function(item) {
      if (item.store == "HomeDepo") {
        console.log(item);
        return (
          <ListItem
            id={item.id}
            key={item.id}
            itemText={item.itemText}
            purchased={item.purchased}
            updateCheckbox={this.updateCheckbox}
          />
        );
      }
    }, this);
```

Try that.

However if you change the function() inside the map to an arrow function it won't be necessary!

```
  const listComponents = this.state.listData.map((item) => {
      if (item.store == "HomeDepo") {
        console.log(item);
        return (
          <ListItem
            id={item.id}
            key={item.id}
            itemText={item.itemText}
            purchased={item.purchased}
            updateCheckbox={this.updateCheckbox}
          />
        );
      }
    });
```

Comment: crescentfresh and @hugo thanks heaps guys, both of those explanations make perfect sense. Both solutions working perfectly.